# How to render Vanilla JS animation in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have to apply some animation to my error page component in angular. I have already designed an animated page using Vanilla JS. Now I need to apply those logics of animation in the script tag to my angular component. How to achieve this?
Please help me.
My code goes here:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="content">
        <h2>404</h2>
        <h4>Opps! Page not found</h4>
        <p>
            The page you were looking for doesn't exist. You may
            have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.
        </p>
        <a href="#">Back To Home</a>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    window.onmousemove = function(e){
        var x = - e.clientX/5,
            y = - e.clientY/5;
        container.style.backgroundPositionX = x + 'px';
        container.style.backgroundPositionY = y + 'px';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Note: Angular2+ removes <script> tags automatically from templates to stop people using this functionality as a ["poor's man" loader](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2766#issuecomment-128005280).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while the preview answer is working fine but in case you want to use the same effect on other element not inside this component angular directive is the perfect use case here.

*BgTiltDirective*

```js
@Directive({
  selector: "[bgTilt]"
})
export class BgTiltDirective {
  @HostListener("mousemove", ["$event", "$event.target"]) handler(
    e: MouseEvent,
    elm: HTMLElement
  ) {
    const x = -e.clientX / 5;
    const y = -e.clientY / 5;

    elm.style.backgroundPositionX = x + "px";
    elm.style.backgroundPositionY = y + "px";
  }
}
```

*template*

```
<div class="container" bgTilt></div>
```

[**demo ‍♂️**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sy4kqb)

Answer (score 3):

if the target element is in the component template

```html
<div class="container" (mousemove)="onMousemoveHandler($event)">
</div>
```

componnet

```js
  onMousemoveHandler(e: MouseEvent) {

    const x = -e.clientX / 5;
    const y = -e.clientY / 5;

    const container = e.target as HTMLElement;
    container.style.backgroundPositionX = x + "px";
    container.style.backgroundPositionY = y + "px";
  }
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jiwjzj)

Comment: happy to help  , if the answer is solve your problem please consider to mark it as accept and vote the answer 